# dart, specify root folder for web

Tags: javascript, build, dart, dart-pub

I want to have some example sites in my web framework package. The sites run ok if I just want to run them as dart only implementations, but if I want to compile them to javascript I currently copy the sub folder out from my packages `/example` directory and into a new packages folders `/web` directory, as I only know how to get dart build to compile the client side code to javascript if its in the web directory. Is there anyway of telling dart build to run in a different root folder? like `pkgRoot/example/example_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pub build example` works fine for me but not yet for Polymer projects (this is work in progress)

Polymer doesn't like when it has a transformer configuration in the package where elements are imported from.

I maintain two polymer elements packages (polymer_elements/polymer_ui_elements).
I have the example files in `example` but use another package (e.g. `polymer_elements_examples`) to build the examples to JavaScript.
This `polymer_elements_examples` has a `pubspec.yaml` file with a dependency to `polymer_elements`, a transformer configuration for the entry pages, and `example` as a symbolic link to `polymer_elements_examples`

I then build the examples in `polymer_elements_examples` with `pub build example`.